# What is the correct way to check if the Size type is empty?

Tags: c#

Assume I have a method like this:

```
public SomeSizeCheckingMethod(Size sizeData)
{
    var isSizeEmpty = (sizeData == new Size(0, 0));
    //some other logic based on this question
}
```

**To check for an empty Size, my options seem to be:**

```
sizeData == Size.Empty
```

**or**

```
sizeData.IsEmpty
```

**or**

```
sizeData == new Size(0, 0);
```

I'd rather not new() up a Size type just to check if I have a dimensionless Size.  Based on the .NET Size documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.size.empty(v=vs.110).aspx) it looks like there are a couple ways I can check for an empty Size but there seem to be some caveats in the *remarks* sections.

Are all of these options functionally equivalent?

Comment: Is the size a custom class? Or from which namespace do you have it? Maybe a simple sizeData == null will accomplish?

Comment: It's a standard .NET type. System.Windows,Size.

Comment: I think Size is struct, otherwise compering with new object wouldnt have sense.

Comment: Those do different things - look at the documentation for `Size.Empty`; it's not the same as `new Size(0, 0)`. "The Width and Height of the instance of Size are equal to negative-infinity when this property is invoked. "

Comment: So it depends on your logic, what is empty for you? `Size.IsEmpty` is not checking a "dimensionless Size". [Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.size.isempty(v=vs.110).aspx): "Therefore, do not use this property to check for a 0 area"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.size.isempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `Size.IsEmpty` will be `true` if either `Width` or `Height` are `0`.

Since you want *both* `Height` and `Widht` to be zero you can easily compare them:

```
var isSizeEmpty = (sizeData.Width == 0 && sizeData.Height == 0);
```

To compare your `sizeData` to `Size.Empty` will not work, because [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.size.empty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

> The Width and Height of the instance of Size are equal to negative-infinity when this property is invoked.

Comparing `sizeData` to `new Size(0, 0)` is simple and clean and looks (to me) a little better than my first variation. But the difference (in performance and memory) will not be measurable.

Comment: I like your first approach more since it doesn't need to create a new `Size`. But you're right, if OP needs to check for a "dimensionless size" he needs to compare the `Width` and `Height`. `Size.IsEmpty` also mentions that it should not be used for this reason: _" do not use this property to check for a 0 area"_

Comment: @TimSchmelter actually not. As @DStanley pointed out, I misunderstood the documentation. `System.Drawing.Size.IsEmpty` checks if _both_ `Height` and `Width` are zero. Anyway, I don't think that there is any _relevant_ performance or memory difference in all those variations.

Comment: But OP uses the [`System.Windows.Size`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.size(v=vs.110).aspx) which works differently: `public bool IsEmpty
        {
            get
            {
                return _width < 0;
            }
        }`

Comment: This wasn't really the answer I was hoping for, but answers the question as asked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If this is `System.Drawing.Size` (WinForms), you can just use the `IsEmpty` property.

However, `System.Windows.Size` (WPF) has a strange `IsEmpty` implementation:

```
public bool IsEmpty
{
    get
    {
        return (this._width < 0.0);
    }
}
```

So if you want to check if it is the default `Size` value, compare it to `Size.Empty` or `default(Size)`

Comment: You're completely right. And the remarks in MSDN were causing me a bit of confusion.

Comment: @axlj `System.Windows.Size.Empty` is _not_ equal to `new Size(0, 0)`! It's rather `new Size(double.NegativeInfinity, double.NegativeInfinity)`! So `new Size(0, 0) == Size.Empty` will be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing to size.Empty should be the best.

have a look to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.size.empty(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks -- I referenced that link in my question :-)

Comment: uhh i didnt recognized the link in the text, sry